# django strange warning for urlconf

Tags: python, django, coding-style, url-routing

Django behaves as I hoped and expected, but gives me a warning. It seems my use-case was not thought about. Which confuses me, **so my question: do I miss any problems waiting for me, or did the developers miss this use case.**

I want the url `person/<slug>/` to point to a detail view, and the url `persons/` to point to the list view. It is more human-readably-correct than beginning with `persons/` in the detail view too. I use include to make the code neater, something like:

```
url(r'^person', include([ 
    url(r'^s/$', views.foo),
    url(r'^/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/form/$', views.form),
    url(r'^/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.bar),
])),
```

Now Django tells me, that the slash at the beginning is unneccesary - which is wrong, leaving it out leaves me with reversed urls `person<slug>` with no slash in between. I do not see why this should be bad style. The warning is:

```
WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '^/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/form/$'
[name='person_form'] has a regex beginning with a '/'. Remove this 
slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an 
include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, the warning is a false positive, but it's a fairly unusual use case, so I don't think that the heuristic in Django necessarily has to be changed.

You could prevent the warning by changing the URL patterns to:

```
url(r'^persons/$', views.foo),
url(r'^person/', include([ 
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/form/$', views.form),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.bar),
])),
```

At first, the warning was for any URLs that started with a `/` ([ticket 23813](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23813)). Then, it was pointed out that there were some cases where it is valid to use a slash, so the warning was disabled when `settings.APPEND_SLASH = False` ([ticket 27238](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27238)).

If you think the check should be amended (or even removed) then the django-developers mailing list or ticket tracker would be a better place to discuss this than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Alasdair.
Just for correctness, it should be ` = False`, right?
Yes, probably the django ticket tracker would be the right place, but it is unusual for me... I mean to report a bug where I'm not sure it is one.
Is there a possibility to mute specific warnings? Then I'd suggest to add a comment about this to the warning.

Comment: You can silence checks with the [`SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#silenced-system-checks) setting. In your case, I think it would be better to change the URL patterns rather than silencing the check.

Comment: I dont think that silencing the slash-check is a good solution either - unless it were possible to silence just _this specific_ warning in that line - which does not seem to be the case. It's probably not worth your time as developers to file a feature request for this. And I wouldn't succeed writing one I fear :) Well, I'll close the question, thank you again.